# Regular Expression to match email addresses with quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I like to check this email address with JavaScript and regex.

Because of quotes and other signs there will be a syntax error. I checked with Firebug.

Now, can anyone send me a possible solution to check this with JavaScript.

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|
"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09
\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-
z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]
[0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z
0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09
\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: Do not do that and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Comment: Is there an email regex that's not very strict but filters out obvious errors, like entering a telephone number in an email field?

Comment: Andomar: ".@." i.e. check for the presence of a “@” and the presence of a character before and after it.

Comment: I tried to make it a long time ago, following all the standards. Then I realized it's not an easy task. After all, a lot of web services CAN'T work with ALL VALID email addresses (I actually never found any) so creating perfect validator seems to have no purpose in real environment. Bottom of line, there's always ONE MORE address to fail for some reason (multiple @s, escape-characters, non-english letters, etc). ex. `abc\@@domain.com`, `abc"abc@xyz.com"xyz@xzy.com`...

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery email validation](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/live-email-validation-with-jquery/)

Comment: It rejects valid mail addresses

Comment: @kmkaplan, course it does (like any others), there's no perfect validation-mechanism.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: No. Not all validation regex reject valid address. For exemple the regex `@` is ok. Of course there is no *perfect* validation mechanism though.